# Adding inline assembly statement in UEFI shell applications

Tags: c, visual-studio

How to add inline assembly statements in a UEFI shell application.
I have added the following statement in the UEFI program:

```
asm volatile ("lgdt %0" : : "m" (*gdt));
```

and i'm getting the following compiler error:

error C2065: 'asm' : undeclared identifier

Thanks.

```
struct desc_ptr { 
unsigned short size;
unsigned long address; 
} __attribute__((packed)) ;
desc_ptr gdt;
```

Comment: try replacing `asm` with `__asm`.

Comment: And I think this is GNU syntax. Show the declaration of `gdt`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I have added the gdt struct definition. but i guess gdt has nothing to do with the compiler error. I have tried __asm too.

Comment: This part `"lgdt %0" : : "m" (*gdt)` is GNU stuff. The Microsoft compiler doesn't understand it.

Comment: BTW. you really should remove the UEFI tag, your actual problem has nothing to do with UEFI, even if you are working on an UEFI shell application.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. Actually I'm trying to port a part of Linux kernel loader to uefi program. I wonder if there is an equivalent assembly code for  msvc's compiler.

Comment: Im' not familiar with the GNU assembly language notation, but it should be something like `__asm lgdt eax`.